# Is the JSON:API spec opinionated about hostnames?

Tags: json-api

Is the JSON:API spec opinionated about the use of hostnames? For instance, my application uses the hostname when scoping records (common for CMS applications). I'm curious if there are any hard opinions in the current spec, or should there be any mention on this in future specs, as to which of the following cases should be used...

```
1. https://app-domain.com/jsonapi/organizations/1/photos/1
2. https://my-organization-domain.com/jsonapi/photos/1
```

Answer (score 1):

The JSON:API specification is agnostic about URL design. There are [some recommendations](https://jsonapi.org/recommendations/#urls) but non of them covers hostnames.